# Jdatepicker not working in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, simpledateformat, jcalendar

I have used `DatePickerCellEditor` for a cell in `Jtable`. When I select a date from the popup calender, the date with `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy` format is displayed. I want to change it to date format (`yyyy-MMM-dd`). 

I did try doing by:

```
DateFormat formatter ;

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");

DatePickerCellEditor datePicker = new DatePickerCellEditor(formatter);

TableColumn po_date = tableModel.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);

po_date.setCellEditor(datePicker);
```

But it didn't work. Can anyone help me with this one?

Comment: "*But it didn't work.*" > Can you explain what didn't work? Do you see an error? Does it display the wrong value?

Comment: which one from `(J)DatePickers`, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame` with `JTable` (one row & cell) with your code for `(J)DatePickers` as `Renderer` & `Editor`

Comment: There was no error but the formatting which i did showed no effect.

Comment: `JCalandar` has no such class. Do you mean `org.jdesktop.swingx.table.DatePickerCellEditor`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs a small change ,

Instead of

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
```

use:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

is that column editable? you should allow that column to be editable overriding method isCellEditable of your TableModel class